# Python Error Handler: Creating a sublist of floats from list of strings

Tags: python, string, exception, type-conversion

I have a list of strings as follows

```
list1 = [' ', '(', '13', 'temp', '1.0E-02', 'given', '42.35', '=', '5']
```

How to get the first 'n' float values? For example the code below gets me the last value of float. How to modify it to get the first n values

```
list1 = [' ', '(', '13', 'temp', '1.0E-02', 'given', '42.35', '=', '5']
for val in list1:
   try:
      float1 = float(val)
   except ValueError:
      continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating to `n=4` since people seem to be getting thrown off by the output.

Here's an approach with map/filter that only prints the first n float elements:

```
n = 4 # Put the number of elements you'd like to see here, for more use 4, 5, etc.
list1 = [' ', '(', '13', 'temp', '1.0E-02', 'given', '42.35', '=', '5']

def get_float(x):
    try:
        return float(x)
    except ValueError:
        pass

for x in list(filter(lambda _: _ is not None, map(get_float, list1)))[:n]:
    print(x)
```

Prints:

```
13.0
0.01
42.35
5.0
```

**EDIT**

To elaborate a bit as requested in comment:

[`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) takes in a function, and an iterable, and applies that function to every element in the iterable, in our case we are trying to map `get_float` to every element, `x`.

Now if `x` is a float, `get_float` succeeds and returns x cast into a float value. If x cannot be cast to a float, the function will throw a `ValueError`, which we don't really need to do anything with - so we pass, and since there is no return statement, we end up returning `None`.

However, after initial pass of our `map`, the `None`s that we got as result of all `ValueError`s end up in the output of the map, so if you printed `list(map(get_float, list1))` would see something like: `[None, None, 13.0, None, 0.01, None, 42.35, None, 5.0]`, with all those extra `None`s.

[`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) takes in a function that returns `True` if you want to keep an element, and `False` if you want to get rid of it, and an iterable, and results in another iterable with only the elements you want to keep. `filter(None, iterable)` just uses the default filter where everything where `bool(x)` evaluates to `False` is discarded. Thus, after applying the filter, we only end up with the floats inside our `filter` iterable, which we cast into a `list`, and slice the outcome of that (`[:n]`) to only keep the first n elements.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on working of filter and map functions

Comment: What about 5.0? Does it not print that? :)

Comment: @Tgsmith61591 the question only asked for the first `n` elements; @WanderingMind editing my answer to elaborate on map/filter

Comment: Ah I see now, I didn't see the 3 in the question, so it didn't register until you said that

Comment: @WanderingMind added more details about map/filter

Comment: Thank you. Now it make more sense

Answer (score 2):

### Option 1

Building on Tgsmith61591's solution: simply get a boolean array to use as index for the list.

```
import numpy as np

def floatable(x):
  try:
    float(x)
    return True
  except:
    return False

floatable_vec = np.vectorize(floatable) 
list1 = np.array([' ', '(', '13', 'temp', '1.0E-02', 'given', '42.35', '=', '5', '0'])
floats = list1[floatable_vec(list1)]
```

Where you vectorize the function so it accepts an entire vector as input, and then simply use the function applied to your list as index to get the desired elements.

### Option 2

You convert your entire array to floats and placeholder values and then filter out the placeholders.

```
import numpy as np

def floatify(val):
  try:
    return float(val)
  except ValueError:
    return np.nan

list1 = [' ', '(', '13', 'temp', '1.0E-02', 'given', '42.35', '=', '5', '0']
floats_raw = np.array(map(floatify, list1))
floats = floats_raw[~np.isnan(floats_raw)]
```

`map` applies the function `floatify` to each element in `list1`. It produces an array of floats and `np.nan` for values that couldn't be converted. The `np.isnan()` function gives an array of booleans that are true for `np.nan` values. The inverse of this boolean array (so only the values that aren't nan) is then used as an index to generate the new array.

### Option 3

If you *aren't* concerned with speed (if your arrays aren't that long) and want a quick and dirty solution, you can stick to a for loop that appends:

```
list1 = [' ', '(', '13', 'temp', '1.0E-02', 'given', '42.35', '=', '5', '0']
floats=[]
for val in list1:
   try:
      floats.append(float(val))
   except ValueError:
      continue
```

### Output

*Notice I changed the input slightly and added a `0` value, this value is a difficult one to filter.*

All the above methods give the following output:

```
In: print(floats)
Out: [  1.30000000e+01   1.00000000e-02   4.23500000e+01   5.00000000e+00   0.00000000e+00]
```

Getting the first `n` values can be achieved by simply getting the first `n` values of the `floats` array:

```
n = 2
floats_fewer = floats[:n]
```

which gives:

```
In: print(floats_fewer)
Out: [  1.30000000e+01   1.00000000e-02]
```

Comment: What if the list contained `'0'` as well?

Comment: yeah, my edited answer was almost identical to yours I guess, but it's different now. I'll add some more to my answer.

Comment: No worries, I deleted my comment

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of kludgey... but, if you want to do it in a comprehension:

```
def floatable(x):
    try:
        float(x)
        return True
    except:
        return False

floats = [float(x) for x in list1 if floatable(x)]
>>> floats
[13.0, 0.01, 42.35, 5.0]
```

Then to get the first `n`...

```
floats[:n]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is quite similar to yours. I have just added the condition *len (floats) < max_floats*:

```
list1 = [' ', '(', '13', 'temp', '1.0E-02', 'given', '42.35', '=', '5']
floats = []
max_floats = 3

i=0
while i < len(list1) and len(floats) < max_floats:
   try:
      floats.append(float(list1[i]))
   except ValueError:
      continue
   finally:
      i+=1

print (floats)
```

So this code produces the following output:

```
[13.0, 0.01, 42.35]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one with regex

```
import re

list1 = [' ', '(', '13', 'temp', '1.0E-02', 'given', '42.35', '=', '5']
print [x for x in list1 if re.match("^\d+?\.\d+?", x)]
```